# RecyclerView.Adapter Class Query

Tags: java, android, android-viewholder, android-recyclerview

While researching on the RecyclerView.Adapter class I came across this line of code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>
```

I am aware of the underlying concept of Adapters and ViewHolders.But I am curious related to the Syntax "MyAdapter.ViewHolder".Is this kind of syntax used in java as well? I am just trying to understand why this piece lies in the Class Declaration? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

MyAdapter.ViewHolder just means that you should implement your own ViewHolder in the MyAdapter class. For instance, if you had named the MyAdapter class, RandomAdapter then inside the <> you should put RandomAdapter.ViewHolder and within the RandomAdapter you should implement the ViewHolder

Check [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465) Step 4

Comment: What is the use of writing it in the class declaration, as I am going to anyways implement the View Holder in the Class.Why such a special treatment to ViewHolder only why not other custom classes that I may write inside the Adapter class?

Comment: Check the reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html It just the way it is implemented in order to cooperate with the Adapter